# I think i'm selecting it wrong #CSS3

Tags: html, class, select, hover

I want to change background-color of element1,2,3 depending on the yellow boxes hover

```
    .box.icon:nth-child(2):hover > .doanimacji.element:nth-child(2) {
       background-color: red;
}
```

it doesn't seam to do the job. What am I doing wrong ?

http://cssdeck.com/labs/je9dvoor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you need with pure CSS, because selectors can't climb the DOM and reach a brother of the initial element (I'm note sure that I'm clear ^^).

You need either to change your HTML template or to use Javascript/JQuery.

Notice that .box.icon selects a DOM element with both "box" and "icon" class (i.e. div class="box icon"). Don't forget to add a space if you want to select a child of your element (.box .icon selects every .icon which is a child of a .box element). And .box > .icon selects the direct children .icon of the .box.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.box').on('mouseenter', '.icon', function() { // mouse enters in yellow square
        var data = $(this).data('nb'); // get the information inside data-nb
        var elem = $('.doanimacji > .element:nth-of-type('+data+')');
        elem.addClass('hovered');
    });
    $('.box').on('mouseleave', '.icon', function() { // mouse leaves yellow square
        $('.doanimacji > .element').removeClass('hovered');
    });
});
```

```css
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #c1c1c1; 
}
.box{
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: auto auto;
    background-color: aqua;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.icon{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}
.doanimacji{
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: beige;
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
.element{
    height: 90%;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

.hovered {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <div class="icon" data-nb="1">1</div>
    <div class="icon" data-nb="2">2</div>
    <div class="icon" data-nb="3">3</div>
    <div class="icon" data-nb="4">4</div>
    <div class="icon" data-nb="5">5</div>
</div>
<div class="doanimacji">
    <div class="element">element1</div>
    <div class="element">element2</div>
    <div class="element">element3</div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/0o1z46u8/

Comment: Wow, that's great. I thought I could manage without js :/
Thanks a lot :)